# Should I pre-register my test user in Stripe for Apple app review?

Tags: appstore-approval, stripe-payments

We're about to submit our new peer2peer marketplace app to the App Store for review. The app uses Stripe for payment processing and a new user to the app has to create a Stripe account before they can list an item for sale in the app. We provide the UI for this within the app for a first time user, but I don't know if I should:

A) have the Apple reviewers go through this Stripe setup so they can verify it's function

or

B) have a Stripe account already created for the Apple reviewer so they don't have to go through this step

I've searched through the Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf

And also through stackoverflow and generally on the interwebs. But haven't found this specific situation answered yet.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?